# List Value gets updated inside an if statement even though the condition is not true

Tags: python

I was trying to scan eight neighboring indices of a particular index (`firstCord`) in a matrix and find whether any of its neighbor is present in another list(`Cord`) containing some random co-ordinates as elements. If any of its neighbor is present in `Cord` list then I would append that particular co-ordinates into `Temp_Cord` list. The code snippet is given below.

I could see that the `Temp_Cord` gets appended with `newCord` value, when the `if newCord in Cord:` condition is satisfied for the first time. Which is expected behavior. But the appended value in `Temp_Cord` changes in every other iteration according to the change in `newCord`, which is like `Temp_Cord[0]` and `newCord` share the same memory. Could someone help me in solving this. I need to append `Temp_Cord` with `newCord` value only when the `if newCord in Cord:` condition is true.

Thank in Advance.

```
Cordlen = len(Cord)
orientation = [(-1,0), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1),(0,-1),(-1,-1)]
firstCord = [0,173]
Temp_Cord = []
while ((Arrlen) < Cordlen):

    newCord = [0,0]   

    for i in orientation:
        newCord[0] = firstCord[0] + i[0]
        newCord[1] = firstCord[1] + i[1]

        if newCord in Cord:
            Temp_Cord.append(newCord)

    Arrlen = len (Temp_Cord)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're appending the *same* list over and over

Why not just use a `tuple` like this?

```
for i in orientation:
    newCord = firstCord[0] + i[0], firstCord[1] + i[1]
```

or if it needs to be a `list` - make a new one each time

```
for i in orientation:
    newCord = [firstCord[0] + i[0], firstCord[1] + i[1]]
```